# batch file creation pse

Tags: batch-file, remote-access, psexec

I'm trying to run a batch file that will connect to the list of ip's on my network, open up cmd then run a list of commands: like ipconfig /all, nbstat -c, arp -a. Then it must save the results into a folder renamed as that "computername".

I already have a batch file made that can do the commands I want and create a folder with the computer, then input the different commands into txt files within that folder.

Here is the WindowsCommands batch file:

```
md %computername%

echo off

echo ARP Command
arp -a >> %cd%\%computername%\arp-a.txt

echo NBSTAT Command
nbtstat -c  >> %cd%\%computername%\nbstat.txt

echo Ipconfig Command
ipconfig /all  >> %cd%\%computername%\ipconfig-all.txt

echo Ipconfig DNS Command
ipconfig /displaydns  >> %cd%\%computername%\ipconfig-displaydns.txt

echo Netstat Command
netstat -ano  >> %cd%\%computername%\netstat-ano.txt

echo Tasklist Command
tasklist /v  >> %cd%\%computername%\tasklist.txt

echo LG Admin Command
net localgroup administrators >> %cd%\%computername%\netlocalgroupadmin.txt

echo Directory Command 
dir C:\Windows\Prefetch >> %cd%\%computername%\prefetch.txt

exit
```

I also created a hosts.txt file that contains my local Ip addresses that I want to run the commands on.

I also created another batch file name psexec for running a For loop.

Now my troubles and arising when trying to run the psexec batch file.

Here is my psexec file:

```
for /f %%a in (hosts.txt) do (
psexec \\%%a C:\Users\ISSG\Documents\WindowsCommands.bat
)
```

Now that is just a rough draft I'm not entirely sure if that is how it should be coded. This is one of the first automated scripts I have ever wrote.

So in a nutshell i need to be able to run this batch file from my local computer- psexec into the IP's. Gather the information and output it into txt files on my local computer.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: you'll need `C:\Users\ISSG\Documents\WindowsCommands.bat` on your remote hosts. Better share the file and call it like that:`psexec \\%%a %localshare%\WindowsCommands.bat`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own questions. The answers get worthless when you do that. If you feel your username is sensitive information, edit that out or flag the question and request it to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If your Batch file doesn't exist in the system directory on all of the computers, you have to use the -c switch to copy it to them in order to run it. It's a good idea to try to ping the computer first to save time trying to connect to it.

```
for /f %%a in (hosts.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%b in ('ping -n 1 %%a ^| find "TTL="') do (
    if errorlevel 0 (
      psexec \\%%a -c -f -u username -p password C:\Users\ISSG\Documents\WindowsCommands.bat
    )
  )
)
```

Also, keep in mind that this will create the folder in the System32 directory on the remote computer. If you want it on your local drive, do something like this:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=2" %%A IN (
  'net use * "\\computer\share"'
) DO IF NOT %%A.==command. SET dl=%%A

if not exist "%dl%\%computername%" md "%dl%\%computername%"

echo ARP Command
arp -a >> %dl%\%computername%\arp-a.txt

echo NBSTAT Command
nbtstat -c  >> %dl%\%computername%\nbstat.txt

echo Ipconfig Command
ipconfig /all  >> %dl%\%computername%\ipconfig-all.txt

echo Ipconfig DNS Command
ipconfig /displaydns  >> %dl%\%computername%\ipconfig-displaydns.txt

echo Netstat Command
netstat -ano  >> %dl%\%computername%\netstat-ano.txt

echo Tasklist Command
tasklist /v  >> %dl%\%computername%\tasklist.txt

echo LG Admin Command
net localgroup administrators >> %dl%\%computername%\netlocalgroupadmin.txt

echo Directory Command 
dir C:\Windows\Prefetch >> %dl%\%computername%\prefetch.txt

Net use %dl% /delete
```

Comment: There are a few options for that. 1. copy psexec to the \windows\system32 directory. 2. Add the path to psexec to the Path environment variable (either manually or using setx) 3. Create a variable in your script with the path to psexec and use it in place of PsExec.exe. 4. Add cd /d %~dp0 to the top of your psexec script and copy psexec to the location you run the script from. You can delete it afterwards if you want.

Comment: Yeah I just entered it in now. When the batch file attempts the second IP. The window won't stay open long enough to see what it displays. I tried to put in a PAUSE command at the end of the WindowsCommands.bat but it only pauses on the first ip.

Comment: I got it to display the error I'm getting. "Error copying C:\Users\ISSG\Documents\WindowsCommands.bat to remote system: The file exists" Not sure if that states it is already there and not going to run the batch.

Comment: I created two VM's with the same credentials and I can get this to work on the VM on my local computer but it still displays error copying to the remote system. Even thou I inputted the correct username/password

Comment: Code updated. Try it now. PsExec needs the -f switch to overwrite the file if it exists on the remote system.

Comment: That's what it should be doing already. The code maps a drive on the remote computer that points to the computer where PsExec.bat is run from. It then creates all of the files in the share specified in the WindowsCommands.bat file.

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=2" %%A IN (
    'net use * "\\ISSG\Network\"'
    ) DO IF NOT %%A.==command. SET dl=%%A

Comment: Ok. So, your computer that you are running this from is ISSG and you have a share on it called network? Go to one of the remote computers. Log in as whatever account you specify as -u -p in the call to PsExec. Map a drive to \\ISSG\Network and write a file to it. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Ahh. No. the share is on your computer. Create a folder that you want to put the folders from each machine in and share it. Change 'net use * "\\yourcomputer\share"' When WindowsCommands.bat runs on the remote computer, it maps the first available drive letter to the share you made on your pc and creates a folder with the computername and puts the files in there. It took me a bit to get my head wrapped around it to write it ;)